# Is it possible to make the HTML <body> transparent in Google Chrome?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, x11

I hope an area of my web page transparent to users in chrome, just like a hole, i.e. users can see behind the browser window's content. I tried set body background-color transparent, but in vain. Does anybody know if this is possible for chrome's current releases?

Comment: If I understand, you want the website to be transparent and to be able to see what's behind chrome browser ? Like the desktop ?
Nope, it's not possible...

Answer (score 1):

Well , behind the body tag is html and it's white , so if you are going to set your body tag transparent you will see nothing but a white color :) So this operation makes no sense in the end.

Answer (score 0):

The default browser background is white, so if you have a transparent body, you'll see white in that area.  There is no HTML control that I know of to change this.

Answer (score 0):

It will be nice if it is possible but heir are no control to do this currently i am sorry.